# Trying to install Kali menu using katoolin but its showing you have unmet dependenies.How do I fix it?

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation, kali, katoolin

Here is the screenshot of the problem

[image: Here is the screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Just do `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` and restart your system if it doesn't disappear... OR better click on `Install all updates`